# How to pass the variable in the twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the `configureShowField` in the admin class. How can I pass the variable from the admin controller to the twig template?

```
->add('places', 'string', array('template'
=>'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_places.html.twig', 'places_array' => $some_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help:

```
    return $this->render(
        'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_places.html.twig',
        array(
            'configureShowField' => $configureShowField
        )
    );
```